# Is there a way to conditionally close the dropdown based upon a value?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm not sure if I can classify this is a bug, but I'm trying to close the dropdown based on a selected value and it seems that 2 clicks need to be pressed in order for this to work. So I'm using the `closeMenuOnSelect` prop and passing a boolean state value that is alternating based if one of the selected values has been chosen. So say I have 3 values (1,2,3) and would like the dropdown to close only if value 1 is selected. However, I have to select the value 1 twice in order for the dropdown to fold away. Here is a quick snippet: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-panini-h3vii

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60616545/react-select-how-to-clear-options-once-user-selected/60617426#60617426

Comment: @keikai it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu can use a combination of `menuIsOpen` and `onMenuOpen` props to achieve this. `closeMenuOnSelect` is being reset during on change event, so obviously in next render of Select it will close menu on select, but current Select wont.

https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-bhabha-rnvfp